# Extended File Watcher

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm using FileSystemWatcher to look for any directory changes. Could I get access name or other data of the process that writes to current directory?
Or maybe from another side - watching for some process and get data about 'where it writes'?

Comment: 'Fraid not: [Is it possible to use the FileSystemWatcher to find the PID or process name that is changing a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248812/is-it-possible-to-identify-what-process-is-changing-a-file-with-filesystemwatche?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112636/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-determine-which-account-modified-a-file-in-shared-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112636/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-determine-which-account-modified-a-file-in-shared-folder)